# How to dynamically change the state in useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, hook

I have a useEffect function that finds an element by it's ID and then if the element has a certain class then it set's the state to be either true or false. However this only happens on the initial load so if I was to click on the button (which is within the FoodList component) that removes/adds the class, then nothing happens. What's the best way to make this dynamic?

```
const [filterExpaned, setFilterExpanded] = useState<boolean>();

useEffect(() => {
    const listPanelToggle = document.getElementById('list-panel-toggle');

    if (listPanelToggle?.classList.contains('list-panel-toggle--collapsed')) {
        setFilterExpanded(true);
        console.log('It does have the class');
    } else {
        setFilterExpanded(false);
        console.log('It does not have the class');
    }
}, []);

return (
  <>
    <FoodList /> // The id 'list-panel-toggle' is within this component
    </>
);
```

Comment: You have provided an empty dependency array `...}, []);` to the useEffect ensuring it will only ever run on mount. Add `filertExpanded` to the array and the useEffect will run whenever `...}, [filterExpanded]);` changes.

Comment: @pilchard I've already tried doing that by sadly nothing happens after clicking the button

Comment: What does the button change? If it's not changing anything in the parent component the useEffect won't run, you would need to pass down a handler to the `Foodlist` component to effect state in the shown component

Comment: @pilchard It toggles the class 'list-panel-toggle--collapsed'

Comment: Wll that isn't a state available in the component you've shown, so there's no way the useEffect would even know about the change

Comment: @pilchard Ahh that makes sense. I'll go back to it and will make some changes. Thanks :)